# Android Resize imageView to fullscreen with orientation

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an xml that contains a imageview and I would like that when clicked, it is resized to the size of LinearLayout taking into account the orientation of the image. And then at a click, replace the image by default.

My Xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/goToDayButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_find_prev"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imgbPrev" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.40"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textNameService"
                style="@style/txtvServiceName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="@string/largetext"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/goToNextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_find_next"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imgbNext"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sentImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/frame_shadow"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/montreal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDescription"
            style="@style/txtvServiceDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to zoom ImageView when it is clicked, and zoom out when it is again clicked. Android has given an [example](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) on this.I thing that might helpful for you.

**Updated** : 
[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNF8pXr6whU) is a good example of similar effect in DevBytes. It is using new API in [ActivityOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html), which is available from JellyBean directly or can be accessed via [support-v4 library](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.html)

The code snipped from that example is here:

```
Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
i.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_COLOUR, colour);
Bundle b = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.eraseColor(colour);
    b = ActivityOptions.makeThumbnailScaleUpAnimation(view, bitmap, 0, 0).toBundle();
}
startActivity(i, b);
```

Comment: I would like the image takes all the space. Thanks.

Comment: do you mean you dont want that transparent region?

Comment: Yes, i don't want the transparent region, i want image extended taking into account the orientation of the image.

Comment: Updated my answer have a look @ThibautSilva

Comment: Do you have a solution for under jellybean? Thanks
Edit: and is it possible to do that in just one activity?

Comment: i have given a support library too for supporting the below versions.